# Go back in the class and get an attribute from another attribute

Tags: java, swing, class, attributes, jcombobox

I have this code:

```
        ArrayList<Integer> codClub = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Club club: clubs) {
           codClub.add(club.getCodClub()); //getCodeClub() simply returns an int value
        }
        ClubComboBox = new JComboBox(codClub.toArray());
        ClubComboBox.setToolTipText("Club");
        ClubComboBox.setBounds(160, 145, 86, 21);
        contentPane.add(ClubComboBox);
```

As you can see, I have a JComboBox with Integer values. Next in the code, I use a function with an integer parameter and I pass the "codClub" selected from the ComboBox.
But I would like to display the name of clubs in the comboBox and go back at the "codClub" using the name. So is possible to go back in the Club class only having the club name("clubName" is a String attribute in Class Club) and get the codClub?

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) Don't use a null layout and don't use setBounds(...). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 2) Add a custom object to the combo box contain both the "name" and "id". Then you can display the "name" for the user and use the "id" to access the club object. See: [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display names of you clubs instead of codes in your comboBox, so you must do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> clubNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Club club: clubs) {
       clubNames.add(club.getClubName()); 
    }
    ClubComboBox = new JComboBox(codClub.clubNames());
    ClubComboBox.setToolTipText("Club");
    ClubComboBox.setBounds(160, 145, 86, 21);
    contentPane.add(ClubComboBox);
```

Than you need another method to get your codClub from the Club class, for that try this method:

```
int getCodeFromClubName (String clubName){  
for(Club club: clubs) { 
if(club.getClubName().equals(clubName))
       return club.getCodClub()
                       }
return -1;
}
```